# is java extends keyword a reference variable?

Tags: java, keyword

I know what extends keyword do in java, but I want to understand what java compiler do when it sees extends keyword.

```
class A{
//some state

//some behavior
}

class B extends A{

}
```

in my opinion when compiler sees extends keywords then it creates super class object to be used in subclass. and I know we can use super reference keywords in subclass constructor to refer to super class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no reference to a superclass object. When you do `new B()`, with your example, there is **one** object created, which has a combination of `A` and `B` features, not separate `B` and `A` objects with a relationship between them. (That would be prototypical inheritance, which is used in several languages, but not Java.)

`super` isn't a reference to a separate object. From [JLS§15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2):

> The form `super`*.Identifier* refers to the field named *Identifier* of the current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of the superclass of the current class.

Sometimes, it seems like there *must* be two separate objects, such as when you shadow an instance field:

```
class A {
    private int field;

    A(int value) {
        this.field = value;
    }

    public void sayField() {
        System.out.println("(A) field == " + this.field);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private int field;

    B(int aValue, int bValue) {
        super(aValue);
        this.field = bValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void sayField() {
        super.sayField();
        System.out.println("(B) field == " + this.field);
    }
}
```

If you do this:

```
B b = new B(1, 2);
b.sayField();
```

...you get ([live copy](http://ideone.com/zQh09D))

```
(A) field == 1
(B) field == 2
```

If there's just one object, how can it be that `this.field` inside `A#sayField` use a different `field` than `this.field` inside `B#sayField`? The answer is: There are two `field` fields in that one object. The compiler tells the code in `A#sayField` to use the first one, and the code in `B#sayField` to use the second.

Comment: Is extends keyword a reference varaible ??

Comment: My main consern is extends keyword . How does it work  ?

Comment: @RidaBatool: No, again, there's no separate object to refer to. I've extended the answer a bit to try to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation .. ok i got the part where you said only one object is created .. but again i want to know about extends keyword what does compiler do when it sees extends keyword

Comment: @RidaBatool: I don't understand what you're asking. When it sees `extends` on a class definition, the compiler looks for the class listed and makes the new class a subclass of it.